# ModuleNotFoundError while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'

Tags: django, heroku

I tried to solve this problem by searching a lot but couldn't find any solutions. I am trying to deploy my django app to heroku from heroku-CLI but got this error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app.settings.local'; 'quiz_api.settings' is not a package
!Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
```

This error happened after settings.py is divided into base.py, local.py and product.py. Before this, there was no problem at all.

```
root
my_project
 -my_app
  -settings
    __init___.py "in settings dir"
    base.py
    local.py
    production.py
  __init__.py "in my_app dir"
  wsgi.py
  etc...
.env
manage.py
etc...
```

base.py (BASE_DIR might be the problem)

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import json

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))






INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    'cloudinary',
    'my_app',

    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
    

    'djoser',
    'corsheaders'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE':8,
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1']

ROOT_URLCONF = 'quiz_api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'quiz_api.wsgi.application'

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

import dj_database_url
MAX_CONN_AGE = 600

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")
    }
}

if "DATABASE_URL" in os.environ:
    # Configure Django for DATABASE_URL environment variable.
    DATABASES["default"] = dj_database_url.config(
        conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=True)


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR , 'media/'


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

manage.py

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings.local')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I thought problem was that my_app or settings were not treated as modules even including **init**.py file, so I tested in local environment, then works fine without any problems.
(in this case, local.py was read)

also, I set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = my_app.settings.production in Config Vars(tried my_app, my_app.settings too) but still return an error which just the massage is different like 'my_app.settings.production'; 'quiz_api.settings' is not a package.
So I lock on the problem is that my app is not treated as a modul while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file simply add this code:

```
import django_heroku

django_heroku.settings(locals()) #Activate django heroku.
```

Try and see if it solves your error

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I installed django_heroku and added it to requirements.txt, then set the above code in settings/base.py. Then wired things happed that the deploy process took more time, and returned the same error. I can see 'built failed' in Heroku activity list, but I can open the app and working fine as API. so some how solved the problem.

Comment: share full traceback error

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quiz_api.settings.local'; 'quiz_api.settings' is not a package
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
django_heroku.settings(locals()) is set after MIDDLEWARE.
For  me, the part 'quiz_api.settings.local' of above message is a bit wierd, because  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = my_app.settings.production in Config Vars is set.